# How to get an object inside another object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongodb-query

This is my collection like,

```json
[
   {
      "column1":"data1",
      "column2":"data2",
      "column3":[
         {
            "column31":"data31",
            "column32":"data32"
         }
      ],
      "column4":"data4"
   },
   {
      "column1":"data11",
      "column2":"data22",
      "column3":[
         {
            "column31":"data312",
            "column32":"data322"
         }
      ],
      "column4":"data44"
   }
]
```

I want to get columns which has `'column1 : "data11"'` and `'column31 : "data312"'`

This is my query, but it returns null object

```js
    collection.find({
        column1: "data11",
        column3: {
            column31 : "data312"
        }
    }).then((item)=>{
        res.json(item);
    }).catch((err)=>{
        console.log(err);
    });
```

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your query like this:

```
collection.find({
    column1: "data11",
    "column3.column31": "data312"
}).then((item)=>{
    res.json(item);
}).catch((err)=>{
    console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: Is there anyway to change "column31" data?
For an example "data312" to "data456"

Comment: Yup, but it is a different query. You should post another question for that.

Comment: Thank you. I will post another question.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use dot notation, otherwise you are telling mongo that matches the entire object.

So this query works:

```
db.collection.find({
  "column1": "data11",
  "column3.column31": "data312"
})
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/SdnrvgDE25D)

Comment: Is there anyway to change "column31" data?
For an example "data312" to "data456"